# Использование файлов C++

Tags: c++, массивы

Я хочу написать на C++ программу, которая заполняет строки двумерного массива `a` и выводит этот массив построчно в файл `output.txt`. Я использую CodeBlocks. После запуска программы она не останавливается, а выполняется до прерывания вручную, а сам файл "output.txt" быстро растёт в размерах. При открытии файла `output.txt` в Windows текстовый редактор не отвечает. В чём моя ошибка?

```
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main() {

    ofstream out;
    out.open("output.txt");
    int a[5][5];
    for (int i; i<4; ++i) {
        for (int j; j<4; ++j) {
            a[i][j]=j;

        }
    }
    for (int i; i<4; ++i) {
        for (int j; j<4; ++j) {
            out<<a[i][j];
            out<<' ';
        }

    }
    out.close();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

При создании переменных их желательно инициализировать

```
for (int i = 0;i<4;i++){
    for (int j = 0;j<4;j++){
            a[i][j]=j;

    }
}
for (int i = 0;i<4;i++){
    for (int j = 0;j<4;j++){
        out<<a[i][j];
        out<<' ';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Ко всему уже отвеченному обращу ваше внимание на то, что при записи в массив `a[i][j] = j` и непонятных значениях `i` и `j` куда хуже другое - вы пишете в непонятное место в памяти. Вам просто не повезло, что программа не вылетела сразу с криком об ошибке (да, это - везение; невезение, когда она в результате неверно работает и дает неверные результаты...)

Comment: Вот был бы там `size_t` вместо `int` и не было бы записи вне массива :)

Comment: Хм.. А как получилось, что файл растёт? Ведь при выполнении условия выхода из первого внешнего цикла, он во второй не зайдёт? UPDATE: Сам понял: там переменные заново объявляются.

Answer (score 0):

Вот так надо, раз у Вас массив 5х5:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i){
   for (int j = 0; j < 5; ++j){
```

Поскольку у Вас начальными значениями переменные i и j не инициализированы, то берутся случайные значения из памяти. В результате записывается не 25 значений, а НАМНОГО больше.